# Как задать формат даты при запросе к БД?

Tags: php, sql

Не получается задать формат даты в запросе:

```
    $orders = $db->query('
    SELECT *,
    DATE_FORMAT(date_add, `%d.%m.%Y`) AS date
    FROM `order` 
    ORDER BY `date` DESC');
```

Выдает ошибку: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 22:

```
     $order = [];
     foreach ($orders as $row) {
     if (!isset($order[$row['date']])) $order[$row['date']] = [];
     $order[$row['date']][] = $row;
     }
```

Если из запроса убрать DATE_FORMAT, то все работает, как надо. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Второй аргумент функции (формат), возьмите в двойные кавычки, а обратные кавычки (_грависы_), используйте для названий полей и таблиц `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(\`date_add\`, "%d.%m.%Y") AS date FROM \`order\` ORDER BY \`date\` DESC`

Comment: @Deonis спасибо!

Comment: обратные кавычки следует использовать, когда  вам посчастливилось в качестве имени таблицы или поля иметь зарезервированное слово или что-нибудь с пробелом в названии. Не надо их постоянно лепить везде, ухудшает читаемость.